# How to filter arrays that contain nan out of an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I know how to filter `nan` out of a simple array.
But what if I have an array of arrays with some of them conatining `nan`,
how do I filter them out?

Example:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3] [nan nan nan] [4,5,6]])
```

and I want the output to be:

```
[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]]
```

furthermore I would like to know the indices where all the `nan` have been in the original array.

I tried using the following:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if np.isnan(np.sum(arr[i])):
        arr=np.delete(arr, i, 0)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work because the index will get out of range after deleting the desired subarrays.

Comment: Iterative deletes have to be run backwards, from the end.  That way the change in the length of the list doesn't mess up the indexing.  Either that or use a list comprehension.  But all that applies to lists, not to arrays.  Repeated `np.delete` in an array is inefficient, even when it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a vectorial way too. Here is an example including a row with both nan and non-nan values:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [4,5,6], [7, np.nan, 8]])

out = arr[ ~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=1) ]
```

out:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I used in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you remove things from an array without having to deal with indexes in a weird way is to start from the end. That way, when you remove something from the middle, any shifts will be on elements you've already gone over.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [4,5,6]])

for i in reversed(range(len(arr))):
    if np.isnan(np.sum(arr[i])):
        arr=np.delete(arr, i, 0)
```